# Rust trait associated type can't indexing

Tags: rust

The data I need to access is the associated type of a trait, but the compiler shows that the associated data cannot be indexed.

My intention is: an instance that implements the GiveMat trait to be able to cache the array data in the mat field, and subsequent computations need to access the elements of the data field in a different instance.
I simplified the problem I encountered into the following code:

```
trait GiveMat {
    type Output;
    fn give_mat(&mut self) -> &Self::Output;
}

struct Arr2 {
    elem: i32,
    mat: Option<[i32; 2]>,
}

impl Arr2 {
    fn new(elem: i32) -> Arr2 {
        Arr2 { elem, mat: None }
    }

    fn calc_mat(&self) -> [i32; 2] {
        [self.elem, self.elem]
    }
}

impl GiveMat for Arr2 {
    type Output = [i32; 2];
    fn give_mat(&mut self) -> &Self::Output {
        if self.mat.is_none() {
            self.mat.get_or_insert(self.calc_mat())
        } else {
            self.mat.as_ref().unwrap()
        }
    }
}

struct Bowl<ArrT: GiveMat> {
    arrs: Vec<ArrT>,
    big_mat: Option<[i32; 4]>,
}

impl<ArrT: GiveMat> Bowl<ArrT> {
    fn new(arrs: Vec<ArrT>) -> Bowl<ArrT> {
        Bowl {
            arrs,
            big_mat: None,
        }
    }

    fn set_big_mat(&mut self) -> &[i32; 4] {
        let mats: Vec<_> = self.arrs.iter_mut().map(|x| x.give_mat()).collect();
        for i in 0..4 {
            if i < 2 {
                self.big_mat.unwrap()[i] = self.arrs[0].give_mat()[0][i]
            } else {
                self.big_mat.unwrap()[i] = mats[1][i % 2 as usize]
            }
        }
        self.big_mat.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Arr2::new(10);
    println!("{:?}", a.give_mat());

    let mut b = Arr2::new(20);
    println!("{:?}", b.give_mat());

    let c = a.give_mat()[1] + b.give_mat()[1];
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

The Compiling error is:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `&<ArrT as GiveMat>::Output`
  --> src/main.rs:49:44
   |
49 |                 self.big_mat.unwrap()[i] = self.arrs[0].give_mat()[0][i]
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `&<ArrT as GiveMat>::Output`
  --> src/main.rs:51:44
   |
51 |                 self.big_mat.unwrap()[i] = mats[1][i % 2 as usize]
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0608`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `Index(Mut)` trait(s)?

Comment: Or maybe you want to change last line to `let c = a.give_mat()[1] + b.give_mat()[1];` ?

Comment: @complikator The notation you gave works if you deal with either instance a or b of Arr2 separately (thanks!). But if a and b are wrapped in Vec, after calling the give_mat method iteratively, the mat field of a or b still cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ArrT` type is generic and can have any `Output` it could also return `i32` for example.
You can further restrict the output type to be indexable by `usize` with the trait changed to:

```rust
use core::ops::Index;
trait GiveMat {
    type Output: Index<usize>;
    fn give_mat(&mut self) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

which will then allow you to write `self.arrs[0].give_mat()[0]` inside the impl for `Bowl` but you run into type mismatches with the rest of your code.